# Sublime text support for Google style guide

Tags: c++, ide, sublimetext, google-style-guide

I am using sublime text 3 for writing C++ code. 
We follow [Google style guide for CPP](https://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/cppguide.html).

I am looking for any plugins which provide auto-reindent and linter support using the style guide as reference.

Comment: clang-format has a Google option IIRC.

Comment: revisiting after a long time .. thanks to @chris i have been using this - https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Clang%20Format

Answer (score 8):

I just tried https://github.com/timonwong/SublimeAStyleFormatter and it seems to be working fine.

You will have to edit the user settings ("Sublime Text" > "Preferences" > "SublimeAStyleFormatter" > "Settings - User") to the following:

```
// This is a simplified settings file that only defines the coding style of your project
{
    "options_default": {
        // Default bracket style
        // Can be either "allman", "ansi", "bsd", "break", "java", "attach", "kr", "k&r",
        // "k/r" "stroustrup", "whitesmith", "banner", "gnu", "linux", "horstmann", 
        // "1tbs", "otbs ", "pico", "lisp", "python", or ""
        "style": "google"
    }
}
```

You can have interesting options like "autoformat_on_save", indentation stuff, etc.